# IIS equivalent to Location tag in Apache

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy, windows-server-2019

I have an app installed on a windows server that uses the port 8090 and I applied a reverse proxy configuration using IIS to make the app available on port 443

however, I used to face problems with the web app, when I contacted the developers they advised me to use apache server on windows and apply the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName demo.somwthing.com
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On 
    SSLCertificateFile ""
    SSLCertificateKeyFile ""
    SSLCertificateChainFile ""
    
    #LogLevel debug mod_rewrite.so:debug
    #LogLevel trace5
    ErrorLog C:\Server\Apache\Apache24\logs\report.txt
    CustomLog C:\Server\Apache\Apache24\logs\custom.txt \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"
    
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
    
    <Location /event-stream>
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .* ws://192.168.11.132:8090%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
    </Location>
    
    <Location /system-event-stream>
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .* ws://192.168.11.132:8090%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
    </Location>
    
        <Location /dashboard-event-stream>
        Require all granted
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade$ [NC]
        RewriteRule .* ws://192.168.11.132:8090%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
    </Location>



    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.132:8090/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.132:8090/
</VirtualHost>
```

I was not able to successfully run apache on windows and we still prefer the IIS for that, for now I was able to apply the rewrite rules and conditions in IIS but I still don't know how to translate the  tag to in IIS, is the location tag in the previous configuration the same as the Match URL?
Please help me to understand the location tag and what it does in this configuration and how to reflect that in IIS

Thanks

Comment: removed the [tag:apache] tag, as this is an IIS question and you "just" use it to describe your objectives. This question is not about Apache httpd.

Answer (score 0):

The URL Rewrite Module in IIS 7 and above provides an import feature that greatly simplifies the process of converting Apache mod_rewrite rules to IIS URL rewrite rules.

More information you can refer to this link: [Importing Apache mod_rewrite Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/importing-apache-modrewrite-rules).

Comment: Thanks you @samwu for the replay

yes I did import the configuration and it is working so far, however, I can't see that it did anything related to the <location> tag from the apache filter.

So I am asking to know if there is any use of the location tag and if I have to do something in IIS for that matter

Comment: Sorry, I did not find the relevant document, but according to the definition of location, you can try to find similar tags in iis. The <Location> directive limits the scope of the enclosed directives by URL, and starts a subsection which is terminated with a </Location> directive. <Location> sections are processed in the order they appear in the configuration file, after the <Directory> sections and .htaccess files are read, and after the <Files> sections.

Comment: Ok that was helpful thank you for that... I think in order to do the same in iis I can apply a filter on the rule to match only some url path ...